# Facebook like button gives an error: This page is either disabled or not visible to the current user

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

The like button on my site was working fine and had more than 270 recommendations but suddenly they disappeared and when I click on the button, it gives an error:

```
This page is either disabled or not visible to the current user.
```

I checked my URL on the debug tool but it gives me the same result each time that appears to be fine.
I have no idea what is the problem or if my site has been blocked by them.
How can I check if its blocked or find the problem?
My URL is: iran.us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link:  http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Firan.us

As for your counts, you specified

http://iran.us (http://graph.facebook.com/http://www.iran.us)

and the counts you're looking for are under

http://www.iran.us/index.php (http://graph.facebook.com/http://www.iran.us/index.php)

The fix for this is your plugin code.

Add `data-href="http://www.iran.us/index.php"` to the plugin code and it will be back to the old like count.  You will not be able to move the 6 current ones over though.